# How much RAM can a 2007 iMac hold?

Tags: imac, hardware, memory

The box says I can add up to 3 GB (for a total of 4GB), but is this restriction hardware based, or because of the operating system?

If I upgrade to OS X 10.6 or higher, can I increase the RAM to 8 GB like the newer models?

Comment: Apple's take on the matter: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1593 Maximum installable RAM is outside of software. The amount only takes into consideration hardware configurations.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MacTracker](http://mactracker.ca), it looks like Apple officially supports a 4GB configuration, but it *can* hold up to 6GB. (This is for model "iMac8,1").